# input type="radio" в форме

Tags: html, css

В форме два инпута с type="radio", при этом получается, что можно выбрать оба [ссылка](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index8/index1.html).  
Что у меня неправильно и как сделать так, чтобы можно было выбрать только один radio, как это и должно быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input) всё написано. 
Если кратко, кажется у них должен быть одинаковый name.

Comment: а, понятно, спасибо!)